# problem adding new point in my chart with draggable points

Tags: highcharts

Good afternoon to everyone

I add a new task in my gantt chart with dragable points.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4937L68/)

But after I create a new task, if i try to drag the new point, i get many errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: f.showDragHandles is not a function
VM28 draggable-points.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: d.firePointEvent is not a function
```

If i disable redraw in addPoint function and move another point, the new point appears and works fine.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4937L68/1/)

I think that i need a special refresh or update.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread and ask for the workaround: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14188

Comment: Thanks! I will be awaiting your response.